# The meaning of "nach" in the quotation below

Tags: german-to-english

How do I translate "nach" in the following quotation:

> ein verkehrtes Urtheil ueber den Kausalzusammenhang der Dinge nach
>   einer mystischen Ansicht der unsichtbaren Welt

Comment: nach= "according to". Seems to be an old quotation ;)

Answer (score 2):

*Nach* has three meanings:

- direction of movement (*towards*, also in abstract sense)
- order in time (*after*)
- sort of reference (*according to* as @beta correctly states)

The latest meaning may be somewhat more infrequent, but is *meiner Meinung nach* still alive and well.